# Is there a service that automatically sends the status of a TYPO3-instance via email?

Tags: typo3, status

The service should automatically send a status-email if there are available updates for the TYPO3-core or extension.
There are solutions for normal websites in the market, f.e. [here](https://status.io/).

I'm looking for something similar but also includes the TYPO3-core and extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this two solutions:

https://www.t3monitor.de

and

"t3monitoring" Extensions (Server and Client) from Georg Ringer
See: https://extensions.typo3.org/?L=0&id=1&tx_solr%5Bq%5D=t3monitoring

to monitor your TYPO3 Installation. Probably there are more out there.